# How to use contact builder in Marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

How to use contact builder in Marketing cloud . I have created Synchronized Data Extensions . But I am not be able to use in journey builder Because there is no option of it .

Comment: Please take some time to review [ask], Make sure you include what you have attempted, what it is you dont understand alongside any links. Once you have done so, please  **[edit]** your post .

Answer (score 1):

Synchronized data extensions aren't available as primary sendable data extensions (see here:  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_implement_synchronized_data_sources.htm&type=5).  Now that you have your synchronized data extension, you will need create a filtered data extension (that is sendable) or use a query activity to populate a sendable data extension for your Journey.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronised Data extensions are available by Navigating to

Contact Builder > Data Extensions

[image]

Comment: SDE is a read only DE via integration. You cannot use them directly within SFMC. Use a SQL and populate the required data from SDE and use them in journeys